# non-constexpr calls in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, c++14

This is a simplified example from code meant to generate sequences of arbitrary values (in the sense of `std::iota`) and iterators of varying categories over them:

```
struct delta
{
    template<typename I>
    void inc(I& i) { ++i; }

    template<typename I>
    I next(I i) { inc(i); return i; }
};
```

There are many classes like `delta`, each defining `inc` differently, e.g. `--i`, `i += step`, `i -= step`, `i *= step`, `f(i)` etc. Function `next` remains the same and is actually shared in a base class.

We are generating the value-based operation of `next` from the mutating operation of `inc`. Doing the opposite would be equivalent, however we choose this design for performance, because `next` is only expected to be called at some initialization, while `inc` may be called a million times.

The problem is that in case some parameters are compile-time constant, I would like to call `next` at compile-time given a `constexpr` argument `i`.

This is not possible in C++11 because of the call to non-`constexpr` function `inc`. Simply changing to

```
template<typename I>
constexpr I next(I i) { inc(i); return i; }
```

or

```
template<typename I>
constexpr I next(I i) { return inc(i), i; }
```

will not work. Of course, we could provide another special function like

```
template<typename I>
constexpr I next(I i) { return i + 1; }
```

but this is too much code duplication, given that there are many classes like `delta` and many other operations like `inc/next`.

I have seen that `constexpr` function restrictions are to be [relaxed in C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions), but I cannot [achieve this in practice yet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2952e38d35e5dacb).

So:

- will this work in C++14 eventually?
- what is the status of standardization?
- what is the status of compilers?
- any possible workaround?

**EDIT**

It seems `inc` should be `constexpr` as well (though `void`). This [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67c28b751ba4f158) on clang 3.4:

```
struct delta
{
    template<typename I>
    constexpr void inc(I& i) { ++i; }

    template<typename I>
    constexpr I next(I i) { inc(i); return i; }
};
```

...but not on gcc 4.8.2. So is the code above correct C++14? Is it only a matter of time for gcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not surprising that this example does not work on gcc, according to this [page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) C++14s generalized constexpr functions are not yet supported.

I believe the source code in your edit is valid C++14, the Draft Standard available [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) contains, on page 126(§5.19) an example that is very similiar to yours(without template, non member functions and they use a temporary):

```
constexpr int incr(int &n) {
    return ++n;
}

constexpr int g(int k) {
    constexpr int x = incr(k);// error: incr(k) is not a core constant
                            // expression because lifetime of k
                            // began outside the expression incr(k)
    return x;
}

constexpr int h(int k) {
    int x = incr(k);
    // OK: incr(k) is not required to be a core
    // constant expression
    return x;
}

constexpr int y = h(1); // OK: initializes y with the value 2
// h(1) is a core constant expression because
// the lifetime of k begins inside h(1)
```

If my reading of the Standard is correct, the fact that yours are member functions should not matter, because "this" is not evaluated and it seems like the code does not violate any of the other rules outlaid in §5.19(2).