# Constexpr call from within another constexpr

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

I know, that such questions were asked early (for example [non-constexpr calls in constexpr functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442942/non-constexpr-calls-in-constexpr-functions)), but let's take next code:

```
consteval int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1));
}

factorial(5);
```

All is OK. We guarantee, that `factorial(5)` expression is resolved at compile time, because `consteval`. Right? If so, I think it should mean, that recursive `factorial(n - 1)` in call factorial(5) is resolved at compile time too. However, we too know, that in declaration `int factorial(int n)` parameter `int n` is just a variable, not `constexpr`. And this influences, if we try to do something like this:

```
consteval int factorial(int n)
{
  // 1 
  constexpr auto res = factorial(n - 1); // error: ‘n’ is not a constant expression
    
  // 2
  return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1)); // hhhhmmmmmm...but all is ok.. 
}
    
factorial(5);
```

What we have?

1. We call consteval function with literal constant. OK.
2. Within consteval function we make recursive call to this function with non constexpr local parameter at row 2. And all is OK, though we call consteval function with non-constexpr value. Well, we can suggest, that compiler knows, that base call has been done as right consteval call `factorial(5)`, and the whole final expression (with all internal code of `factorial`) should be interpreted as consteval. Yes? Or, why? Because...
3. At row 1 we explicitly make a call as constexpr with non-constexpr value. And we get an error.

My question is next: why for explicit consteval call of `factorial(5)` compiler makes difference between explicit and implicit constexpr recursion call of factorial? Is it bug or feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's review what a constant expression is. A *core constant expression* is an expression which, when evaluated, does not cause one of a long list of "bad" behaviors. A constant expression is a core constant expression whose result is "allowed" by some other rules (not important here). In particular, note that these conditions are *heavily non-syntactic*: a constant expression are not defined *positively* by defining what expressions are constant expressions, but *negatively* by defining what constant expressions can't do.

A result of this definition is that an expression can be a constant expression even it requires the evaluations of many non-constant expressions (even non-core constant expressions). In the definitions

```
consteval int factorial1(int n) {
  if(n == 0) return 1;
  else { // making this correct since undefined behavior interferes with constant expressions
    /*constexpr*/ auto rec = factorial1(n - 1);
    return n * rec;
  }
}
consteval int factorial2(int n) {
  return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial2(n - 1);
}
```

the `factorial1(n - 1)` in `factorial1` is not a constant expression, so adding `constexpr` to `rec` is an error. Similarly, the `n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial2(n - 1)` in `factorial2` is *also* not a constant expression. The reason is the same: both of these expressions read the value of (perform lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on) the object `n`, which did not start lifetime within the expression. But this is fine: ***the bodies of `constexpr`/`consteval` functions are simply not checked for being constant expressions.*** All `constexpr` *really* does is whitelist a function's *calls* for appearing in constant expressions. And, again, an expression can be constant (like `factorial1(5)`) even if you need to evaluate a non-constant expression on the way (like `factorial(n - 1)`). (In this case, when evaluating `factorial1(5)`, the lifetime of the `n` object that is the parameter to `factorial` *does* start its lifetime within the expression being checked, so it can be read during evaluation.)

Two places where an expression *will* be checked for being a constant expression are initializations of `constexpr` variables and "non-protected" calls to `consteval` functions. The first one explains why adding `constexpr` to `rec` in `factorial1` is an error: you're adding an additional check for a constant expression that *is not* done in the correct `factorial1` function, and this extra check (correctly) fails. This should have answered your point 3.

For your point 2: yes, there's a special "protection" for `consteval` functions called from other `consteval` functions. Usually, a call to a `consteval` function is, right at the point it is written, checked for being a constant expression. As we've been discussing, this check would fail for the calls `factorial1(n - 1)` and `factorial2(n - 1)` in the above definitions. There is a special case built into the language to save them: a call to a `consteval` function in an *immediate function context* (basically, whose immediately enclosing function is *also* `consteval`) is not required to be a constant expression.